# How to know if the context has been cancelled?

Tags: go, go-context

How to know if a context has been cancelled?

In a following sample code,

- There are 2 tasks.
- If any of these tasks completes first, I want to know in other tasks through context cancel.
- As part of example, task2 will always finish first (before task1).

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func task2(ctx context.Context, ch chan int) {
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        if ctx.Err() != nil {
            // In case task1 completes first,
            // I want to print this error. How do I reach this block?
            fmt.Println("Cancelled 2", ctx.Err())
        }

        fmt.Println("Task2 ===== ", i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        if i == 2 {
            ch <- 2
        }
    }
}

func task1(ctx context.Context, ch chan int) {
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        if ctx.Err() != nil {
            // In case task2 completes first,
            // I want to print this error. How do I reach this block?
            fmt.Println("Cancelled 1", ctx.Err())
        }

        fmt.Println("Task1 ----- ", i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        if i == 5 {
            ch <- 1
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    ch := make(chan int)

    go task1(ctx, ch)
    go task2(ctx, ch)
    
    d := <-ch
    cancel() // If either of task1 or task2 completes, invoke the cancel() func

    fmt.Println("Task which completed first: ", d)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your channel is unbuffered, `task1` will deadlock in `ch <- 1` since you only have one read on `ch` in `main()`. To fix this, you can turn this into a select-statement where you check for `ctx.Done()`:

```golang
if i == 5 {
    select {
        case ch <- 1:
            return
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Cancelled 1", ctx.Err())
            return
    }
}
```

You can do the same in `task2`.

Do notice that when `main()` terminates, any go routines still around will terminate along with it, no matter what they were in the process of doing. If you do not want that, you need to provide additional synchronization, for example using a `sync.WaitGroup` like so:

```golang
func a(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("a is done!")
}

func b(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(time.Second*2)
    fmt.Println("b is done, too!")
}

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    go a(wg)
    go b(wg)

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Everyone is done! We can terminate without interrupting anyone.")
}
```